# Forma correcta de mostrar array

Tags: c++

¿Qué forma es la mas recomendable para mostrar un array en una funcion?

```
typedef int TVector[10];
```

1. con `const`:

   ```
   void MostrarArray(const TVector &v){}
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. directamente:

   ```
   void MostrarArray(TVector v){}
                     ^^^^^^^^^
   ```

#### Código

```
int main() {

    TVector v;

    MostrarArray(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el objetivo de `mostrarArray` es tan sólo mostrar sus datos por pantalla, la opción correcta es referencia (para evitar copias) constante (pues no se espera que sea modificado).

El alias `TVector` que has usado limita el uso a arrays estáticos de `10` elementos, pero si necesitaras una función `mostrarArray` para arrays estáticos de tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación podrías usar esta alternativa:

```
template <std::size_t TAMANYO>
void MostrarArray(const int (&v)[TAMANYO]){}

int main()
{
    TVector v{};
    int x[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int y[]{1,2,3,4,5};

    MostrarArray(v);
    MostrarArray(x);
    MostrarArray(y); // esto seria error con la version que recibe const TVector &

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mí me parece que estando por salir el estándar C++17, y ya en pleno uso el C++14 y el C++11, francamente no es conveniente dedicarle más tiempo y energía a las formas que eran habituales hace más de 18 años atrás. Así que yo te diría que una de las formas preferidas en C++ es usar std::vector como contenedor por defecto, a no ser que se decida por otro (como std::list, std::deque, std::array u otros).

Usando un std::vector, la forma más simple y habitual creo que es

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void mostrarArray(const std::vector<int>& a)
{
    for(const auto& i : a)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    mostrarArray(a);
}
```

Comment: El problema de esta aproximación es que el array facilitado tiene tamaño dinámico mientras que [Akarin](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20645/2742) pide un tamaño fijado a `10` elementos; para ello debería usarse [`std::array`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).